# New Computer keeps crashing on fresh install

Tags: debian, linux-mint, wifi, ssd, crash

I have a brand new HP Envy dv7-7212nr, second one, because I thought there was something wrong with the SSD with the first one. After I install Debian Testing or Mint, I compile the wireless drivers. Everything works perfectly. Then after about a day it seems like the SSD crashes. When I don't install the wireless drivers, it does not crash. When I boot into a live CD to see what happened, the SSD partition is corrupt, it has to be formatted. I have no idea what's going on. Is there anything that I can do?

Could it be that I am using the AMD64 bit version?

Comment: Just don't use out of tree drivers. Ralink has fine in-kernel drivers. Upgrade your kernel if the chipset is really new, [build](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation) [backported drivers](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) if you can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the wireless driver is corrupting memory.
It probably sets up DMA incorrectly.

Please ask the linux-wireless mailing list for help.
At minimum, they will need the PCI and driver information of your adapter.

Also test whether a 32-bit kernel exhibits the same problem. (How much memory do you have?)

Comment: I have 8 gigs of RAM

Comment: Thought so … you might try a test with less RAM (4G).

Comment: The computer is a very compact laptop.

Comment: Hmmm. Boot with mem=3G then.

Comment: So I updated the kernel to 3.8, and added mem=3G to grub, now when I try to compile the driver I get `mixed implicit and normal rules. Stop.`

Comment: It's very odd, when I was using Mint, and upgraded to kernel 3.7, the driver compiled, but when I upgraded to 3.8, the driver would not compile.

Comment: If the driver doesn't compile for 3.8 there was a kernel change which the driver isn't ready for. Ask for an update.

Comment: Also, this appears to be an out-of-kernel driver. :-/  I'd recommend an USB stick WLAN interface until it gets fixed. (Did you report the problem to the driver's author?)

Comment: I have been thinking about getting an external wireless card or just returning the computer. Also the author the the wireless card Ralink is now owned by some other company, and I don't think they update drivers or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following 2 things to start.

1. I would make sure that there isn't any known issues with that particular SSD card by looking it up on the manufacturers website. Make sure you note the serial number and model number and possibly a lot number when looking to see if there are any known issues with it.
2. I'd try and confirm that the SSD is not faulty by running some sort of software that would exercise it throughly. In my searches I came across [this Q&A on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/282301/quick-method-to-determine-ssd-drive-health) that gave some good tips and references for various methods for diagnosing bad SSD hardware.

Comment: 1. My SSD is really, it's not on Samsung's website. I can find hardly any info on it.

Comment: 2. This is the second SSD with the exactly the same problem. I tested the first SSD and it was very healthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have debian installed you will need a newer kernel as 3.2 will not support ivy-bridge correctly.
There are many ways, I do use debian wheezy/testing and also have unstable and experimental in my source.list with apt pinning this is really easy to achive.

Comment: When I was using Mint I used 3.7 kernel, and the same thing happened.